# Pandas: Create New Dataframe That Contains A Column For Total Rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, rows

I have the following dataframe: df_Discrep_73L_3 that has a total of 601 rows 
I have a second dataframe: df_Discrep_73Y_3 that has a total of 391 rows

I want to create a Dataframe that has the following:

```
ID  Total Rows
73Y 601
73L 391
```

I know to use df_Discrep_73L_3.shape to find the number of rows but don't know how to put it in the above dataframe.

Comment: Do you have a lot of DataFrames you need to do this with, or just like a few?

Answer (score 0):

The .shape method returns a tuple in the form (rows,columns). You can save these by using shape[0] and shape[1] respectively.

```
rows_73L = df_Discrep_73L_3.shape[0]
rows_73Y = df_Discrep_73Y_3.shape[0] 

pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["73Y", "73L"], 'Total Rows': [rows_73Y, rows_73L]})
```